Identify this movie - A.I System
I've been trying to find this movie for quite some time, but no luck.
I do remember some scenes from it.
The first is that the A.I system uses a phone to communicate with a man.
I remember this man uses his belt to kill the lights to test a system that he created (on his first job) and then he tells the owner that he needs a key to 'unlock' that system if the power ever goes down (failsafe I guess).
The guy goes to somewhere on the planet and meets a taxi driver, this driver is actually a "hacker" and helps him somehow.
The driver gets impressed with the phone and I remember a quote (or close to it) "Here in (the country) we don't have radioshack, you only have me).
At the end the A.I wants to move to his system (the one he made).
I hope you guys can help me, and I apologize for some grammar mistakes!
Thank you!

The movie is called Echelon Conspiracy. 
Here are the details :
In the movie, Max (Shane West) is a computer engineer. He receives an anonymous courier in which he gets a phone (it's a new model phone that no one has). He receives messages instructing him to do stuff. If he doesn't do them, he received threatening messages. 
The phone instructs him to go to Prague and gamble at a casino. And with the instructions, he hits the jackpot. The casino security try to catch him. Just as they are about to catch him, FBI arrive and capture him. They interrogate him about the phone and how he came about it. So they set out to find the sender of the messages
They find out it is Echelon (NSA's Supercomputer) that is sending the message and not a real person. It instructs Max to transfer it to another place so that it can upgrade itself. 
These are the scenes OP asked.
